# Warning 404 - GET /detectfiles/sc/skins/standard/images/blank.gif

Tags: css, image, smartgwt

I am using gwt-2.4 and smart-gwt 2.4, 
I have commented out the  tag for standard.css file from my gwt.xml, I am not using any themes.

I have been experimenting with programmatically disabling items in a DynamicForm. When I set any TextItem fields to disabled in Internet Explorer 8, a small red cross appears over the item. It appears that it is looking for the file \sc\skins\standard\images\blank.gif.

On my console Following error is displayed.
[WARN] 404 - GET /detectfiles/sc/skins/standard/images/blank.gif (127.0.0.1) 1432 bytes

my gwt xml file is as follows:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.widgetideas.WidgetIdeas' /> 
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.libideas.LibIdeas' />
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>  
<inherits name='com.renault.commonparts.commonparts' />
<entry-point class='foo.bar.myentrypointclassname'/>
```

My html file is as follows:

```
    <!doctype html>
  <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css\detectfiles.css">
       <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css\corp.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\print.css" media="print" />

       <title>Detect Files</title>

             <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="detectfiles/detectfiles.nocache.js"></script>
         </head>

          <body>

       <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1'     style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

        <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color:   red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
           Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
            in order for this application to display correctly.
          </div>
         </noscript>

 <table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td>

    <!-- Page Header -->
        <div>somecode</div>
    <!-- /Page Header -->

<div>
<table align="center" class="table" border="0">
 <tr>
     <td>

       <table>
        <tr></tr><tr></tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="dfPage">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
          </table>
       <br/>

       </div>
   </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my code I have following line:

```
final DynamicForm startForm = new DynamicForm();
startForm.disable();
```

Comment: Please improve your question.

Comment: ok. Please post small relevant amount of code then. also include your gwt.xml file

Comment: updated my question with my code

Answer (score 0):

OK. When I want to disable an SmartGWT element I usually use (can't tell if there is a difference with disable :

```
startForm.setDisabled(true);
```

Don't know if it matters, but you should be careful with HTML tags (don't forget the ending slashes).

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css\detectfiles.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css\corp.css" />
```

Comment: @Madhura, try to isolate your problem. Try commenting out all yours CSS includes. In a way that you would keep only the necessary tags.